# does go get module always look in pkg.go.dev?

Tags: go, prometheus

I want to use latest prometheus in my project. The latest code in github.com/prometheus/prometheus is at version v2.34.0

when i do `go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus` in my module, i get this line added to my `go.mod`

```
require github.com/prometheus/prometheus v2.5.0+incompatible // indirect
```

but this is not the one i want. i want latest code as in the repo.

i checked https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/prometheus , there it shows the version is `v2.5.0+incompatible`, and was published on `Nov 6, 2018`

Does `go get <module>` always look in `pkg.go.dev` or is `pkg.go.dev` facing same issue as i am facing?

i tried going to `GOMODCACHE` and deleting the module version `v2.5.0+incompatible` and trying `go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus@latest` but it again pulls same version.

How do i get the latest source of prometheus in my mod cache?

Edit:
I was suggested to run `go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus@v2.34.0`, this is what i get

```
$ go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus@v2.34.0 
go: github.com/prometheus/prometheus@v2.34.0: invalid version: module contains a go.mod file, so module path must match major version ("github.com/prometheus/prometheus/v2")
```

Comment: *"Does go get <module> always look in pkg.go.dev "* -- `go get` *never* looks in `pkg.go.dev`.

Comment: thanks, then why am i getting older version pulled?

Comment: Have you tried `go get github.com/prometheus/prometheus@v2.34.0`?

Comment: @mkopriva edited the question to add result of your suggestion

Comment: 2.5 is old https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/tag/v2.5.0

Comment: i cloned the repo to local machihe. how do i get this into my go module cache ?

Comment: If the module doesn't follow the [major version](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-version) suffix rules that are required to support `go get ...@vX.Y.Z`, then you can try the [pseudo-version](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-pseudo), i.e. the commit hash. Since the hash of [2.34.0](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/tag/v2.34.0) is `881111f`, you can try `go get -u github.com/prometheus/prometheus@881111f`, then in the `go.mod` file you don't need to pay attention to the `vX.Y.Z` number, what matters is the timestamp and hash (`20220315145411-881111fec433`).

Comment: And to answer your question: *"then why am i getting older version pulled?"* -- That, I believe, is because of [MVS](https://go.dev/ref/mod#minimal-version-selection).

Comment: @mkopriva doing `go get -u github.com/prometheus/prometheus@881111f` solved the issue. Thank you so so much.